# Split main.js in Angular6 into multiple files

Tags: webpack, angular6

I am using Angular 6 once I build main.js is around 8 mb as we build this application I expect to grow bigger. Is there a way to split this files into multiple files so that they load faster? Is there a way to implement delayed loading when it is required.

```
chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.44 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.d2ed080a489df2acb65c.js (main) 8.27 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.991eda935898a57f5c1f.js (polyfills) 59.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.5bc2644258354e9b9ba3.css (styles) 680 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.92795880e21717c67f9d.js (scripts) 40.3 kB  [rendered]
```

angular.json

```
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true,
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: You can do lazy loading in Angular, but splitting files won't actually make anything faster if you still need all of the files for the app to start.

Comment: yes but i was thinking at least it will be able to download in parallel by the browser

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I strongly recommend you to update Angular version.
Yes, you can split `main.js` to several chunks, but I think that lazy loading is what you need to make your application faster.

**Angular CLI split chunks steps**
From the [docs](https://angular.io/cli/build): using `Angular CLI` options you can split `common` and `vendor` chunks.
You can add these settings to project's `angular.json` or use it directly:
`ng build --commonChunk --vendorChunk`
But I think these options can be unavailable in angular v6. 
Anyway you can do the same things using custom builder (see below).

**Custom split chunks steps**
Change builder in angular.json and add path to webpack.config.js to use custom webpack configuration for build and serve:

```
       "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
                 "path": "./webpack.config.js"
              },
...
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
```

in `webpack.config.js` you can do everything webpack can do. Here is an example for `shared` chunk:

```
module.exports = function(base) {
    return {
        ...base,
        optimization: {
          ...base.optimization,
          splitChunks: {
            ...base.optimization.splitChunks,
            cacheGroups: {
              ...base.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups,
              myCustomChunk: {
                test: /MyCustomRegexpToGrabFiles/, // search files by pattern
                enforce: true,                     // always split this chunk
                name: 'myCustomChunk',             // name will be myCustomChunk.js
                chunks: 'all'                      // split it from lazy and common chunks
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

For more example check out SplitChunksPlugin [docs](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).

**Lazy loading steps**
Lazy loading with webpack will always create separated chunk.
Basically you should just follow this [guide](https://v6.angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) for Angular v6.