# How can I chunk main.js to reduce initial loading?

Tags: angular

In my angular application, size of the main.js bundle is so high that, initial loading is too  much. How can I split main.js and reduce initial loading?
In my project architecture, lazy loading is not suitable.
How can I achieve the same?

[image]

Comment: what is the size in MB ?

Comment: @SyedMohammadFahimAbrar, 4.40 MB

Comment: is that compressed prod size?

Comment: can u try ahead of time? ng build --aot --prod

Comment: peep here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062744/split-main-js-in-angular6-into-multiple-files